# Vue mounted jquery code not working on DOM re-render

Tags: vue.js, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to use jqueryui datapicker with vue. The input for the datepicker is inside a template if-else condition.
The datepicker works just fine initially but after flipping back and forth using the template if-else it stops working.
It seems the jquery code is no longer mounted after a DOM re-render.

```
<template v-if="...">
    <input name="startdate" id="startdate" v-model="date"  type="text">
</template>
<template v-else>
    <div>Some other display</div>
</template>

mounted: function() {

    $('#startdate').datepicker({
        onSelect:function(selectedDate, datePicker) {            
        this.date = selectedDate;
    }
    });
```

I placed the jquery code instead inside "updated" and it works now, but this code gets called every single time there is a DOM change.
I'm wondering it there is a better way to accomplish this?

```
updated: function () {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
  ....
  ....
```

Comment: if you could show more code, especially where the updated block is. then i might be able to help.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I would consider using a vue based datepicker. There are enough of those around and using jQuery and Vue together gives more headaches than it's worth. Vue can cover virtually every scenario that jQuery can and is easier to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use `v-show` instead. This will only toggle the `display` value of the element, not remove from or add to the DOM, so any event handlers attached won't be affected. From the Vue docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show

That said, @Imre_G is probably right about finding a Vue datepicker to use.

Comment: Thanks I removed my template if-else and replaced with divs + v-show and it works! I will look at a vue only datapicker. In my current env I only had access to vue, jquery and jqueryui libraries. I'll recommend adding a vue datepicker plugin thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: use your component with mouted() hook and just add to your component the `v-once` directive. Like this: `<input name="start date" ... v-once>`

But, as mentioned in Imre_G comment, consider to use some premaded Vue datepicker component. It is far more better idea as mixing Vue with jQuery.